# I can't see proxies for Azure Function App

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app-proxy

I have created an azure function app in VS 2017.
i've included a proxies.json file and published the app.
However I can't see the proxies in the Azure portal.

All it says is:
**Proxies (preview) (Read Only)**

I have gone into function settings, and there  are no settings to enable proxies. I think that was the old method, (not for developing the function in visual studio)

proxies.json looks like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/proxies",
  "proxies": {
    "user": {
      "matchCondition": {
        "methods": [ "GET" ],
        "route": "/user/{user}"
      },
      "backendUri": "https://<mycontainer>.blob.core.windows.net/html/test.html/{user}"
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok I figured it out....
the proxies.json file should have copy to output directory as "**copy always**" in the properties panel in VS.